# Can Path.GetTempFileName() ever cache?

Tags: .net, temp

I have an odd problem... and I think I have narrowed it down to a point where we create a temporary file using `Page.GetTempFileName()`.

I sometimes get a error message stating that `Cannot create a file when that file already exists.`

Is there a chance that using `Path.GetTempFilename()` could generate the same filename and become cached?

I am changing my code to use:

```
Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), string.Concat(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), ".xls"));
```

In the hope that this will generate a unique filename, but I am concerned that the same problem may arise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Path.GetTempFilename() creates an actual file on disk; depending on what you're doing once you have that filename you could be triggering something.  It's written to return an actual file to avoid the race conditions associated with older temp filename methods from the past (notably tmpnam in the C standard library, for example.)

Note that it will throw exceptions if there are more than 65,535 files created with this method without deleting them, or if it can't generate a unique filename.

So, what are you doing with that filename after you get it back from Path.GetTempFilename()?

Comment: We use a SyncFusion library to generate an Excel (xls) file from some data returned. so we `Move` the file from `.tmp` to `.xls` and then use the `SaveAs` to write to the file. once we are done we usually delete the file. Sometimes this doesnt happen it appears...

Comment: Well, the call only validates that the name is not in use with the .tmp extension.  When you rename it, do you first check that you don't already have a file with that name but with .xls?  How many files are in the temp directory when this fails (and does it fail all the time after that, or only occasionally?)

Comment: Its only occasionally. So it might be reusing an existing filename because it doesnt exist as a tmp... interesting. I am hoping that the above change I mentioned, about creating the file using a guid works. I've even added a while loop to check if the file exists and regenerate a new name if it does just to be safe.